# How can I connect twincats between two PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ads, plc, twincat

I met an error when I test the connection:

**Target PC**

1. runs windows
2. runs Twincat3 and plc
3. TARGET_PC_ID = "144.214.174.72" and TARGET_AMS_ID = "169.254.42.168.1.1"

**Client PC**

1. runs windows
2. runs Twincat3
3. Client_PC_ID = "144.214.174.69" and CLIENT_AMS_NET_ID = "144.214.174.69.1.1"

I have set the route on the target PC using Twincat. Here is my python script on Client PC:

```py
import pyads
TARGET_AMS_ID = "169.254.42.168.1.1"
TARGET_PC_ID = "144.214.174.72"
plc = pyads.Connection(TARGET_AMS_ID, 851, TARGET_PC_ID)
plc.open()
print("state",plc.read_state())
```

But an error happened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxwan/Desktop/py_keypoint/test_plc.py", line 14, in <module>
    print("state",plc.read_state())
  File "C:\Users\xxwan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pyads\connection.py", line 237, in read_state
    return adsSyncReadStateReqEx(self._port, self._adr)
  File "C:\Users\xxwan\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\pyads\pyads_ex.py", line 510, in adsSyncReadStateReqEx
    raise ADSError(error_code)
pyads.pyads_ex.ADSError: ADSError: target machine not found    Missing ADS routes (7).
```

Whether I need to add route on my client PC (Similar to that on the target PC)? BTW, how to get the real port number on the target PC?

Comment: Hi nanqi, welcome to StackOverflow. You can find the [port number as explained here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/31064331.html?id=9222201567644391707). It is most likely the default 851. Can you can establish a connection the the target PLC from the [TwinCAT system manager](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_system/html/tcsysmgr_systemnode_subnodes_routes.htm?id=5662381071116974088)?

Comment: You also need a route one the client PC. The route on the target is used to allow client connections. The route on the client is used to find the target (i.e. convert ams net id in to an IP address).